# How do you load just one component when using aurelia-syncfusion-bridge with aurelia-cli

Tags: syncfusion, aurelia

Windows x64

aurelia-syncfusion-bridge 1.0.0

syncfusion-javascript 15.3.26

I would like to use just the grid component and its necessary and optional components but building traces all components.

Per install instructions the plugin is set to syncfusion.useAll() and I did not see any other documentation about changing this setting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for your interest in Syncfusion components.

We can use required component by modifying couple of steps followed in the below user guide documentation.

https://help.syncfusion.com/aurelia/getting-started/aurelia-cli-integration

- In `aurelia_project/aurelia.json` file, modify the following lines which was already configured in `build.bundles.dependencies`. [here](https://help.syncfusion.com/aurelia/getting-started/aurelia-cli-integration#aurelia-cli-configuration)

  ```
    {
      "name": "aurelia-syncfusion-bridge",
      "path": "../node_modules/aurelia-syncfusion-bridge/dist/amd",
      "main": "index",
      "resources": [
        "grid/*.js",   // <--- Required files --->
        "common/template.js" // Remove this, if template rendering not required
      ]
    }
  ```

  - Register the `aurelia-syncfusion-bridge` plugin with Aurelia in our `main.js` file which is in `src` folder. [here](https://help.syncfusion.com/aurelia/getting-started/aurelia-cli-integration#aurelia-cli-configuration).

    ```
    .plugin('aurelia-syncfusion-bridge', (syncfusion) => syncfusion.ejGrid().ejTemplate()); 
     // Remove ejTemplate(), if template rendering not required
    ```

For your convenience, we have prepared sample and attached below.

[Sample](http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/185974/ze/aurelia-syncfusion-cli-193790916)

How to run.?

Run the below commands in the sample's root location.

```
npm install
au run --watch
```

Thanks,

Karthick T